# How to add a header to form url after redirected back?

Tags: php, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

How would I add header to the response to this?

```
public function handleDonate($data, $form)
{
    $donate = DonationForm::create();
    $donate->FullName = $data['FullName'];
    $donate->Amount = $data['Amount'];
    $donate->Email = $data['Email'];
    $donate->Message = $data['Message'];
    $donate->SponsorshipPageID = $this->ID;
    $donate->write();
    return $this->redirectBack();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`redirectBack()` returns a `HTTPResponse` object, so you can manipulate that before you return it:

```
return $this->redirectBack()->addHeader('X-Foo', 'Bar');
```